# Convert date field to Quarter in R

Tags: r, date-format

I have data frame which has the date column in format `08/21/2000(m/d/Y)`.

Now I want to add new column which display the date in **Quarter** format that is `2000-Q3`.

I install *zoo* package and used following command. but it is giving `NA` value.

```
library(zoo)
mydf$var9=as.yearqtr("mydf$Order.Date","%m/%d/%Y").
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes around `mydf$Order.Date`: `as.yearqtr(mydf$Order.Date,"%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Thank you. i got it. it worked. if i want Q3-2000 like this then where i should change the syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zoo library has created a set of functions to handle year-quarter vectors:

```
library(zoo)
mydf$var9=as.yearqtr(as.Date( mydf$Order.Date, "%m/%d/%Y" ).
```