# How to convert Dates to Quarters in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a panel data set in the below format

```
Individual    Date
A             05/10/2010
A             06/11/2011
A             21/07/2012
B             22/02/2010
B             15/03/2011
B             28/09/2012
```

I want to convert the date to Quarters such that Quarter for 2010 should be 1,2,3,4....and Quarter for 2011 should start from 5 until 8...and Quarter for 2012 should start from 9 until 12.

Can anyone please suggest a code to do this in R?

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349910/convert-date-field-to-quarter-in-r), or many others.

Comment: It's prob not a dupe. OP is looking for the quarters count to continue into the following years. Most likely best to create a quarters vector stretching from the first date to the last.

Comment: or, starting from `a$yq <- as.yearqtr(a$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`, you can do `a$yq_num<-sapply(sub("\\d{3}(\\d)\\sQ(\\d)", "4*\\1+\\2", a$yq), function(x)eval(parse(text=x)))` to get what you want

Answer (score 3):

```
library(zoo)
df$Date <- strptime(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
x <- as.numeric(as.yearqtr(df$Date))
firstyr <- as.numeric(as.character(strftime(min(df$Date), "%Y")))
df$quarter <- (x-(firstyr-1))/.25-3
#   Individual       Date quarter
# 1          A 05/10/2010       4
# 2          A 06/11/2011       8
# 3          A 21/07/2012      11
# 4          B 22/02/2010       1
# 5          B 15/03/2011       5
# 6          B 28/09/2012      11
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="    Individual    Date
    A             05/10/2010
    A             06/11/2011
    A             21/07/2012
    B             22/02/2010
    B             15/03/2011
    B             28/09/2012", header=T)
```